# MySQL: Where price < 50, sum(price +14)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum, case

I'm building a query that will automatically add shipping charges to an items price if it is less than $50, and another, higher, shipping charge if it has a raw price of more than 50. I've done some experimenting with CASE, IF, and SUM but I'm not sure which is the one I need.

Initial:

```
Stock_Number    Line Part_Number Q  T   Price
AAB_1074901519, AAB, 1074901519, 1, AM, 120.67
AAB_1074908119, AAB, 1074908119, 1, AM, 108.29
AAB_1264907619, AAB, 1264907619, 1, AM, 364.49
AAB_1294908319, AAB, 1294908319, 1, AM, 368.97
AAB_1378254,    AAB, 1378254,    1, AM, 36.18
```

Desired:

```
AAB_1074901519, AAB, 1074901519, 1, AM, 144.67   //Because price > 50, +22
AAB_1074908119, AAB, 1074908119, 1, AM, 130.29   //Because price > 50, +22
AAB_1264907619, AAB, 1264907619, 1, AM, 386.49   //Because price > 50, +22
AAB_1294908319, AAB, 1294908319, 1, AM, 390.97   //Because price > 50, +22
AAB_1378254,    AAB, 1378254,    1, AM, 50.18   //Because price < 50, +14
```

Anil solved my issue. Thanks to everyone for your effort!

> You can use case statement. Here is the query. Substitute table names
>   and column names.
>
> select case when price < 50 then price + shipping cost else price end
>   from your table;

Comment: Start by sharing your table as text table and your expected results also as text table

Comment: show us what you tired.

Comment: subquery with the case statement, alias case as price_s, outer query sum(price_s)

Comment: also, this doesn't sound like a good idea at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case statement. Here is the query. Substitute table names and column names.

```
select case when price < 50 then price + shipping cost else price end from your table;
```

Comment: Brilliant! You solved my problem. Thank you so much. I'll be using that syntax for other validations I've wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this UPDATE:

```
update table set price= case
when price<50 then price+shipping_fee1
else price+shipping_fee2 
end;
```